# Undefined index: BlogPost почему ругается, если я сделал этот элемент массива выше?

Tags: php, массивы, yii2

```
$new_post = array(
        "BlogPost" => array(
                "body" => "blabla"
        )
);

if (null !== (Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $new_post = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $blog_post_model->body = ($new_post["BlogPost"]["body"]);
}
```

на new_post в ифе регается Undefined index: BlogPost 
почему ругается, если я сделал этот элемент массива выше?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что ты его переопределил в этой строке:

```
$new_post = Yii::$app->request->post();
```

Не работал с Yii, но имея опыт с Laravel, могу предположить, что $new_post после переопределения стал не массивом, а объектом.

UPD.: Почитал доки, нет, объектом не становится, но тем не менее, было переопределение и созданные ячейки изначально (в первой строке) – их уже нет.

Comment: Спасибо.
Я хотел, чтоб эта конструкция работала в экшене, который работает и при пустом _POST. Видимо, надо кнопку формы которая делает _post сажать на отдельный экшн, который будет срабатывать, когда _POST есть наверняка

Comment: Ты можешь использовать следующую конструкцию:

    Yii::$app->request->post('name', 'default value if empty');